# How do i pass a number password in Jenkins pipeline.?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to use a number password eg(123455) for a specific use case. I have to write the password in a yaml file that is in turn used in a project. But since the jenkins job is passing all the parameters as string, there are single quotes that appear around the password eg ('123455') when i try to write it to the yml file.

code:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Salesforce') {
            steps {
               script{
                  def amap = [:]
                  int value = Integer.parseInt("${username}")
                  amap["client_id"]="XXXXXXX"
                  amap["client_secret"]= value
                  amap["username"]='XXXXXXX.com'
                  amap["password"]="${password}"
                  amap["host"]="XXXXXX.my.salesforce.com"
                  writeYaml file: '/salesforce.yml', data: amap
```

Here the `${username}` is being fetched from a password or a string parameter.

Comment: even if password contains digits - normally it's a string or could be represented as a string. not clear where is a problem...

Comment: The problem is I do not need a string. I need it to remain number.

Comment: Hi @ashishsrivastava, show us your code please.

Comment: sure.ive updated the code in the edit

Comment: Have you try `amap["password"]=Integer.parseInt("${password}".toString())`

Comment: @yong
Yes. i tried this, gettting below error:
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "123455"
 at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:583)
 at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:766)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.StringGroovyMethods.toInteger(StringGroovyMethods.java:3312)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$1160.doMethodInvoke(Unknown Source)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
 at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
 at

Comment: seems your password variable already contains double-quotes

Comment: could you show the output of this command: `echo "${password.getClass()} >>${password}<<"`

Comment: Its as below: 

class java.lang.String >>****<<

Comment: I finally got it. it was a stupid mistake. I was using parseInt to get a 8 digit number. so there was intrinsic conversion and hence there were single quotes around the number. it was fine when i used parsefloat()